# how to draw subset of a series with jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I need to draw three series on a same canvas. The series are similar as:

```
rec1 = [0,  0,   150, 200, 0  ];
rec2 = [60, 120, 179, 240, 300];
rec3 = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];
```

I use below source codes to draw the series.

```
$.jqplot("chart", [rec1, rec2, rec3], {
    title: "",
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        rendererOptions: {
            smooth: false
        },
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            ypadding: 10
        },
        showMarker: true,
        lineWidth: 2
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        location: 'nw',
        placement: "outside"
    }
});
```

In rec1, the elements which has a zero value will always be zero. I want to hide these zero-value-elements in rec1. Is there any way to realize this?
Set rec1 to be:

```
rec1 = [undefined, undefined, 150, 200, undefined]
```

will hide these undefined points, but causes point labels of 150 and 200 appearing at wrong positions, as shown by the picture.
Thanks for any useful directions.

[image]

Comment: Not clear, looks good http://plnkr.co/edit/CsXtTvM4L3BoCBKvf8xq?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for your reply, but I cannot help myself out by referring to the link you gave.

Comment: Which version of the jqPlot are you using? I have tried too and I have no problem too...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie Version 1.0.8 of jqplot. I am not sure if I did anything wrong in my program. But I checked with my best ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "flat" array, you should use a 2-dimensional array in order to place your points :

```
rec1 = [[3, 150], [4, 200] ]; // we defined 2 points with their (x, y) coordinates
rec2 = [60, 120, 179, 240, 300];
rec3 = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];
```

I have made a jsfiddle showing this (I have just move the point `[3, 150]` at `[3, 90]` from your example in order that you see the correct place of its label) : http://jsfiddle.net/5wgcqyet/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the method you posted, it works exactly the way I wanted.